# Why does the select2-removing event not trigger in select2 with allowClear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to hook an event in my [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation) once it gets cleared. The select2 was initalized with `allowClear: true`. Yet the event

```
$select.on('select2-removed', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

does not trigger when resetting the select2 with the clear button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the select2 source code, the `clear` method use the event `select2-clearing` instead of `select2-removing`. So you should listen to this event too.

`select2-clearing` and `select2-removing` are triggered **before** the removal. `select2-removed` is triggered after.

Keep in mind that `clear` does not always trigger the `select2-removed` event. It look like this event is triggered only if an element is actually removed from the input.

Answer (score 15):

select2 v4.0.3

```
$('#smartsearch').on('select2:unselecting', function (e) {
    alert('You clicked on X');
});
```

For all the [select2 Options & Events](https://select2.github.io/options.html)

Comment: As an addendum, `unselecting` fires *before* selection is removed, `unselect` *whenever* it is removed.

Answer (score 10):

For me the only thing that worked is the `'select2:unselect'` event... (In non-multiple select box)

Answer (score 6):

I got it working with the `'select2-removed'`-event instead of `'select2-removing'` when using the clear button.

As to why it does not trigger still eludes me.

Comment: @Jatt.net Nope. I did not. But once I did I figured, what the hell, I might just add a question on so to ease my pain ;)

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to get data about the element just got removed on removed event. Following code worked for me;

```
 $('#selector').on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
        var data = e.params.data;           
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with 4 or above version then use

```
$('#id').on('select2:unselecting', function (e) {
    alert('You clicked on X');
});
```

Below 4 version

```
$('#id').on('select2-removing', function (e) {
    alert('You clicked on X');
});
```

Make sure for 4 or above version it is **select2:unselecting** **colon(:)**
Less than 4 version it is  **select2-removing** **-(hyphen)**