# How to capture event when allowClear option of select2 is chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-events

I've tried to capture `select2:clearing` event

```
$("#my-select").on("select2:clearing", function (e) {
    console.log('cleared');
});
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/p2uyc1ej/))

but it is not fired. I've also tried other versions (like `select2:removed` etc., see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558101/why-does-the-select2-removing-event-not-trigger-in-select2-with-allowclear) with similar problem), but it also doesn't work.

I use select2 4.0.0-beta2.

Comment: Never used this library, but in the docs a dash is used in the event names instead of a colon, e.g. select2-clearing

Comment: @MarioA, I've tried dashes, but the current doc (see https://select2.github.io/examples.html, Events section) says about colon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The changelog of select2 4.0.0-beta2 states:

> Removed events
>
> ```
> select2-clearing - Use select2:unselecting instead
> ```

https://github.com/select2/select2/releases

Comment: strange.The event select2:selecting is working, see: http://jsfiddle.net/1vgLnjbb/1/

Comment: I assume that this is an error in the beta version. You should submit a bugreport on github

Comment: You are right, Mario - https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2954. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "select2:unselecting Triggered before a selection is removed. This event can be prevented." but `console.log($select.select2('data'))` on this event returns an empty array

Answer (score 19):

This works:

```
$("#my-select").on("select2:unselecting", function(e) {

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#my-select").on("select2:select select2:unselecting", function(e) {
   //do something here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

> According to the select2 [event documentations](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events), all of the *unselect, unselecting, clear and clearing* events will works !

But consider that *usnselect* or *unselecting* events should be used by **single selection** mode, and *clear* or *clearing* should be used by **multi selection** mode. So the clear or clearing will fires if all of selected items cleared or clearing.

The differences between unselect and unselecting, is that unselecting fires before removing selection so you can prevented it.

Hope that it helps.