# How to prevent unselect event after allowClear has been clicked in select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I know for this related question that the `unselecting` event can be used to trigger actions before clearing some selected options:
[How to capture event when allowClear option of select2 is chosen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28065551/1863970)

But it is triggered as many times as selected options are already. And if I clear one of the options it is triggered too. (see http://jsfiddle.net/6rphh6d3/)

I want to trigger some actions, but only when the `allowClear` button is clicked, and only once.

So far I've thought about:

1. Using this event and filter somehow where it comes from.
2. Replacing the logic of the `AllowClear._handleClear` function.

I'm using select2 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but seeing as I've ended up here again I believe this is what you where looking for.

```
var data = [
{id: 0, text: 'enhancement'},
{id: 1,text: 'bug'},
{id: 2,text: 'duplicate'}];

$(".js-example-data-array").select2({
    data: data,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    allowClear: true
}).on("select2:unselecting", function(e)
{
    $(this).data('state', 'unselected');
            }).on("select2:opening", function(e) {
                if ($(this).data('state') === 'unselected') {
                    $(this).removeData('state'); 
                    return false;
                }    
            });
```

Not the most elegant but works